# Structure: Comparing strings in an array inside of a structure - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, strcmp

Having trouble understanding an assignment. The way we were taught in class is different than our lab instructor's assignments so I am quite confused.

We were given a program and we have to fill out a function to complete the program. It includes a structure with 4 elements. The function we create is one that takes in 2 arrays that were initialized in a separate function that was already completed, and the length of both of the arrays. They get this info from the input file and it's already scanned into the program. So the function needs to read if two movie titles are the same. If it is, then it returns the higher one. If there is more than one set of movies that are the same, it adds up both of the more expensive movies.

Now logically, I feel I have the right idea and I feel like this should work, but of course it doesn't. The movie lists that you compare are in the two separate arrays, so I'm supposed to compare a title from one array to a title of the other array and go through the arrays until the length is reached.

[Full instructions if needed](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cop3223/labs/L12/COP3223Rec-Structs.pdf)

My code: The function created is getProfit and none of the parameters or rest of the code can be changed. That's why I find it confusing because we can't do it the way we learned.

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char title[100];
    int runTime;
    int idtag;
    double salePrice;
} DVD;

double getProfit(DVD* list1, int len1, DVD* list2, int len2) ;
double max(double a, double b);
DVD* get(FILE* ifp, int len);

int main() {

    FILE* ifp = fopen("dvd.in", "r");
    int numCases, loop;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numCases);

    // Go through each case.
    for (loop=0; loop<numCases; loop++) {

        // Read in movies.
        int len1,len2;
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &len1);
        DVD* myMovies = get(ifp, len1);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &len2);
        DVD* yourMovies = get(ifp, len2);

        // Output sale price of all common movies.
       printf("%.2f\n", getProfit(myMovies, len1, yourMovies, len2));
        // Bookkeeping...
        free(myMovies);
        free(yourMovies);
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}

// Pre-condition: list1 is an array of length len1, list2 is an array
//                of length len2. No title appears in either list more
//                than once.
// Post-condition: Returns the sum of the sale prices of the common
//                 DVDs in both lists. Two DVDs are considered the
//                 same if their titles are identical.
double getProfit(DVD* list1, int len1, DVD* list2, int len2) {
    int i, j;
    double sales = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < len2; j++){
            if(strcmp(list1[i].title, list2[j].title)){
                if(list1[i].salePrice < list2[j].salePrice)
                    sales += list2[j].salePrice;
                else if(list1[i].salePrice > list2[j].salePrice)
                 sales += list1[i].salePrice;
            }
        }
    }

    return sales;
}

// Returns the larger of a and b.
double max(double a, double b) {
    if (a > b) return a;
    return b;
}

// Reads in len DVDs from ifp and returns those store in a dynamically allocated array.
DVD* get(FILE* ifp, int len) {
    DVD* res = malloc(sizeof(DVD)*len);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        fscanf(ifp, "%s%d%d%lf", res[i].title, &(res[i].runTime), &(res[i].idtag), &(res[i].salePrice));
    return res;
}
```

Input File:

```
2 
3 
BackToTheFuture 108 1234567 15.99 
Gremlins 120 13232423 9.99 
IndependenceDay 135 2312412 12.99 
2 
Gremlins 123 13232425 13.99 
MonstersInc 95 44232122 15.99 
5 
a 100 1234213 14.99 
b 101 1245332 7.99 
c 102 3431533 12.50 
d 103 3431434 19.99
e 104 4314133 16.47 
4 
f 120 5314443 11111111.38 
e 104 5134343 16.48 
d 110 3431414 14.99 
c 105 1234145 14.50
```

What the output should return:

```
13.99
50.97
```

What my output is:

```
61.96
55555738.73
```

I know for a fact my strcmp line is not working, I mean it's obvious. I originally had it `strcmp(list[i].title, list2[j].title == 0)` but the program crashes before it even starts.

Nobody needs to give me a straight answer, some guidance would be great please. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `if(strcmp(list1[i].title, list2[j].title)){` --> `if(strcmp(list1[i].title, list2[j].title)==0){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm ashamed :). I was putting it within the strcmp parentheses. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Don't be ashamed, it won't be the last time the answer is staring you in the face.... However, you may want to look at a C style guide. Generally C favors all lower-case variable names instead of *camelCase* variables -- leave those for C++. One example [**NASA C Style Guide**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf) (Goddard Spaceflight Center 1994)